# mongodb aggregation get all fields sum group by date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a143a79ca78479b1dc90161"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-21T14:38:49.375Z"),
    "amount" : 227.93359186,
    "pair" : "ant_eth"
}
```

Expected output

```
{
  "12-12-2012": [
    {
     "pair": "ant_eth",
     "sum": "sum of amounts in 12-12-2012"
    },
    {
     "pair": "new_pair",
     "sum": "sum of amounts in 12-12-2012"
    },
  ],
  "13-12-2012": [{
    "pair": "ant_eth",
    "sum": "sum of amounts in 13-12-2012"
  }]
}
```

What I achieved so far from my knowledge is;

```
const criteria = [
  { $group: { 
    _id: '$pair', 
    totalAmount: { $sum: '$amount' } } }
]
```

Any help to achieve the expected output is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you want to sum up amount by just the date portion of a datetime and pair, and then "organize" all the pair+sum by date.  You can do this by "regrouping" as follows.  The first `$group` creates the sums but leaves you with repeating dates.  The second `$group` fixes up the output to almost what you wish except that the dates remain as rvals to the `_id` instead of becoming lvals (field names) themselves.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {d: {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt"}}, pair: "$pair"}, 
       n: {$sum: "$amount"}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.d", 
      items: {$push: {pair: "$_id.pair", sum: "$n"}} 
    }
  }
]);
```

If you REALLY want to have field names, then add these two stages after the second `$group`:

```
,{$project: {x: [["$_id","$items"]] }}
,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$x"} }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could get to:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {
                "$year": "$createdAt"
            },
            month: {
                "$month": "$createdAt"
            },
            day: {
                "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt"
            },
            pair: "$pair"
        },
        sum: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        }
    }
}])
```

For rest of the thing, you probably need to do app side parsing to generate output you want